# Send a Click via Javascript console (chrome broswer console)

Tags: javascript, browser, console

The whole webpage is like a javascipt container/iframe (i dont know the term) where there isn't really any element to click on. I basically want this click to keep alive the webpage. is there any way to send a random mouse event or random (or even specific) keyboard activity through the browser's javascipt console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code as below :D

```
const sendUserInteraction = (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.value); // you can pick out the info user made with it
}

window.onload(() => {
   document.body.addEventListener("click", sendUserInteraction);
   document.body.addEventListener("keydown", sendUserInteraction);
})
```

Comment: may i ask what this code actually does, please?

Comment: also it replies something with "VM6974:5 Uncaught TypeError: window.onload is not a function
    at <anonymous>:5:8"